# Cordova Phonegap and jqueryMobile : keyboard overlay input text?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I work with `cordova`, `phonegap` and `jquery` mobile , 
on android devices keyboard cover text input when its open . 
(on IOS it works well)

I just tested:

`preference name="fullscreen" value="false"`

```
 `meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-      scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"`


 `$(document).ready(function(){
          $("input").focus(function(){
            $('html body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 2000);
          });
        }`
```

**What is the solution?**

Comment: i not work direct with cordova but in phonegap build i use a plugin to get the keyboard height, and after i resize the container of my info. something like window - keyboardHeight and after i scroll the container to the offset of the input text, may be this can give you an idea

Comment: Look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html for `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` - test that and give us feedback if that helped you.